# Can JWT be used across different AngularJS Apps?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I have a Laravel 5.1 API that is connected to an AngularJS Frontend.

Can I do this..

1. Have one (hosted on mydomain/public) AngularJS App with the sole purpose of authenticating the user and getting a JWT token from the Laravel API Backend
2. Somehow passing this same Token to a second (hosted on mydomain/secure) AngularJS in order to authenticate the user and the access the App.

I know the token is saved on the local storage so I don't see a reason why I can not or would I have to merge the two apps together.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. They are not related to the number of Ng-App or instances of Angular apps you define.

How JSON Web Tokens Work ??

A browser or mobile client makes a request to the authentication server containing user login information. The authentication server generates a new JWT access token and returns it to the client. On every request to a restricted resource, the client sends the access token in the query string or Authorization header. The server then validates the token and, if it’s valid, returns the secure resource to the client.

So server logic is not dependent on if your front end is single page or multi page.

You can read this post for more clarity:

http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs